# Biblatex entry field for actual paper keywords to be printed

Tags: biblatex, keywords

Using bibtex the keywords field was often used for the actual metadata keywords associated with, e.g., a published paper, but in biblatex the keywords field is intended for the bibliography filters and "are usually not printed". That is, the meaning of the keywords field has changed: it is now used for, e.g., sorting entries depending on subject rather than being a placeholder for the actual metadata in a paper. Hence, the question is now: for the purpose of storing and possibly printing the keywords that appear in the paper metadata, what field or other solution would be the correct/recommended place to put the paper keyword metadata in?

(A similar field which still exists is the abstract field which is still intended for the paper abstract. In this regard an old bibtex entry can be reused as is.)

Comment: Just out of interest, can you give examples of BibTeX styles that use `keywords`. On my machine I only found `refer.bst` (`keywords`), `bibtoref.bst` (`keywords`), `abstract.bst` (`keyword`). `btxdoc` doesn't mention `keyword` or `keywords`.

Comment: @moewe Services provide the means to import/export publication data in the form of BibTeX entries, and the `keywords` field is often used for the publication _keywords_. For example, all research publications and student theses produced in Sweden are supposed to be registered in a national portal, see [link](https://info.diva-portal.org/about-diva/). Metadata regarding abstract, keywords, DOI, author, title, publisher, etc., is needed, and the most convenient way to provide this metadata is to import from a BibTeX database, and the field `keywords` is supposed to contain the ... keywords.

Answer (score 3):

If you like you can tell `biblatex` to print the contents of the `keywords` field.

The contents of the field are not hidden from `biblatex`, they can be printed. But the field has a special format – it is not a normal list, which is separated with `and`, but a list comma-separated values, for which `biblatex` has no built-in `\print...` function. So we need to do some of the stuff `biblatex` would normally do for us ourselves.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{keyword,keywords}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  keyword  = {keyword},
  keywords = {keywords},
}

\newcounter{cbx@keyword@total}
\newcounter{cbx@keyword@count}
\newcommand*{\keywordscount}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{cbx@keyword@total}}

\newcommand*{\keywordsprint}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{cbx@keyword@count}%
  \ifnumless{\value{cbx@keyword@count}}{2}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space}%
  #1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{keywords}{%
  \setcounter{cbx@keyword@total}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@keyword@count}{0}%
  \forcsvlist{\keywordscount}{#1}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@keyword@total}}{1}
    {\bibstring{keywords}}
    {\bibstring{keyword}}%
  \addcolon\space
  \forcsvlist{\keywordsprint}{#1}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{keywords}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author   = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title    = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date     = {1980},
  keywords = {civil-service,importance},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service. Keywords: civil-service, importance.]

---

If you are not wedded to the idea of using `keywords` and its csv format, you can define a new, normal list field and use that.

Since this solution uses `biblatex`'s normal list facilities, we can cut down on the helper functions we needed above.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{printkeywords.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{printkeywords.dbx}[2020/03/16 add printable keyword list to biblatex data model]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=literal]{printkeywords}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{printkeywords}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, datamodel=printkeywords]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{keyword,keywords}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  keyword  = {keyword},
  keywords = {keywords},
}

\DeclareListWrapperFormat{printkeywords}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{1}
    {\bibstring{keywords}}
    {\bibstring{keyword}}
  \addcolon\space
  #1}

\DeclareListFormat{printkeywords}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:plain}%
  #1\isdot}


\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{printkeywords}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author        = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title         = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date          = {1980},
  printkeywords = {civil-service and importance},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output of the MWE is the same.